# Not able to access array values through a pointer

Tags: c++

```
int *ptrr;
int array[3];
for(int i=3;i>0;--i){
      array[i]=i*100;cout<<array[i]<<" "<< & array[i]<<endl;
}
ptrr=array;
for(int i=3;i>0;--i){
    cout<<*(ptrr+i)<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
for(int i=3;i>0;--i){
    cout<<ptrr[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<ptrr<<" "<<*ptrr<<" "<<*ptrr+1<<*ptrr+2<<endl;
```

I have a basic question that I am able to access the array elements through a pointer in a loop, but when accessed separately it pops out weird values. The pointer is same still giving different values. What is the problem..?

Output:

```
300 0x7ffface5538c
200 0x7ffface55388
100 0x7ffface55384
300 200 100 
300 200 100 
0x7ffface55380 -1394257008 -1394257007 -1394257006
```

Comment: You're getting out of the bound of the array. Change all `for(int i=3;i>0;--i){` to `for(int i=2;i>=0;--i){`.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use `*(ptrr+1)` and `*(ptrr+2)`. `*` has higher priority than `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different issues in your code.

First your loop iterator is wrong. Your array is of size 3 (valid indices are 0, 1, 2), so there is no array[3] (this memory location is out of scope).

you should rewrite your loops like given below

```
for(int i=2;i>=0;--i){
      array[i]=i*100;cout<<array[i]<<" "<< & array[i]<<endl;
}
```

Secondly you should use () in below statement.

```
cout<<ptrr<<" "<<*ptrr<<" "<<*ptrr+1<<*ptrr+2<<endl;
```

and rewrite your statement as

```
cout<<ptrr <<" "<<*ptrr<<" "<<*(ptrr+1)<< " " << *(ptrr+2)<<endl;
```

The syntax *ptrr is perfectly fine but since you had started your loop from i=3 and terminated at i>0 (i.e. i=1) so array[0] remained uninitialized and garbage value was assigned. But with the initialization in my answer it will work.